# Javascript Wrapping Callback as Promise Equivalent in Java 8 using CompletableFuture

Tags: javascript, java, promise, callback, completable-future

In Javascript, I can wrap a callback as a promise as folllows:

```js
function subscribeAsCallback(request, callback) {
    // ... async operation
    const response = ...; 
    callback(response); 
}

function subscribeAsPromise(request) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        subscribeAsCallback(request, (response) => {
            resolve(response);
        });
    });
}
```

So that I can call it with

```js
subscribeAsPromise(request).then(response => {
   // handling response logic
});
```

And I would like to ask **what is the equivalent of it in Java?** Here is my code in Java, where I have no idea how to wrap the callback up.

```java
public class DataSubscriber {
    public void subscribeAsCallback(Request request, Consumer<Response> consumer) {
        // ... async operation 
        Response response = ...; 
        consumer.accept(response); 
    }

    public CompletableFuture<Response> subscribeAsPromise(Request request) {
        // ... ? 
        // what is the equivalent of its Java version?
    }
}
```

So that I can call the code as follows:

```java
dataSubscriber.subscribeAsPromise(request).thenApply(response -> {
   // handling response logic
});
```

Comment: Maybe one of the [20 examples of using CompletableFuture](https://dzone.com/articles/20-examples-of-using-javas-completablefuture) I found by searching will be what you want

Comment: Have you looked at `runAsync()`?

Comment: how can I use runAsync() to return `CompletableFuture<Response>`?

Comment: @CHANist pass the `subscribeAscallback()` method into the lambda function of `runAsync()`. Example [here](https://hellokoding.com/java/runasync-supplyasync/)

Comment: @codemax sorry, still cannot figure it out, can you provide me a more concrete example?

Comment: @CHANist can you share more code for the javascript's `subscribeAsCallback`?

Comment: @codemax Actually I want a generic approach that wrap a callback as a promise, therefore any callback will do, even if it is not async. e.g. `function subscribeAsCallback(request, callback) {callbcak(1)};` just return 1 as response is still fine for me, as long as you can wrap the callback as completableFuture nicely.

Answer (score 0):

I just think of a solution using `CountDownLatch`, though I don't think using CountDownLatch is a good idea, as it just block the thread from execution which wastes some resources. But it will be one possible solution for that.

```java
public class DataSubscriber {
    public void subscribeAsCallback(Request request, Consumer<Response> consumer) {
        // ... async operation 
        Response response = ...; 
        consumer.accept(response); 
    }

    public CompletableFuture<Response> subscribeAsPromise(Request request) {        
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            try {
                final Response[] responeResult = { null }; 
                CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
                subscribeAsCallback(request, new Consumer<Response>() {
                    public void accept(Response response) {
                        responeResult[0] = response;
                        latch.countDown(); 
                    }
                });

                latch.await();
                return responseResult[0]; 
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException(ex);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Though the code does not look very nice, it is the first solution I can think of. Hope there are other better answers so that I can learn upon.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to pass `callback` into `CompletableFuture`. I personally find it easier to handle `promises` in `JavaScript` and definitely more verbose in `java`.

In your example, I don't see the point of passing in the anonymous function `(response) => { resolve(response); }` to `resolve` the `promise` or `future` since `CompletableFuture` provides a `get()` method to resolve the `CompletableFuture`, which is called after your line of code

```java
CompletableFuture future = dataSubscriber.subscribeAsPromise(request).thenApply(response -> {
   // handling response logic
});

// do this to "resolve" the future
future.get();
```

```java
public class DataSubscriber {
    // Please update the name to reflect the correct semantic meaning
    public Response subscribeAsCallback(Request request) {
        // ... async operation 
        Response response = ...; 
        return response;
    }

    public CompletableFuture<Response> subscribeAsPromise(Request request) {
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(this::subscribeAsCallback);
    }
}
```

Comment: For example, if I am requesting data through socket, I can easily retrieve the data using callback. Definitely Promise will return once only, while Socket can return many times, but if I ensure such contract does exists, then I can easily wrap the callback through socket using Promise in Javascript (see the code above). But how could I do that in Java?

Comment: I think we need more context and code. For example, why do you even need to create a `CompletableFuture` if you are using sockets? Shouldn't the data be handled in an event handler?